# Prove $\ln\big(\frac{21}{10}\big) \leq \sum_{n=10}^{20} \frac{1}{10n}\leq \ln\big(\frac{20}{9}\big).$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

Please help. I have been trying his question for the past 2 hours and cant seem to go anywhere with it.

$$
\ln\big(\frac{21}{10}\big) \leq \sum_{n=10}^{20} \frac{1}{n}\leq \ln\big(\frac{20}{9}\big).
$$

Comment: Compare a Riemann sum with the integral.

Comment: Since $\frac{1}{x}$ is monotonically decreasing for $x >0$, $\int_{10}^{21} \frac{1}{x} \ dx < \sum_{n=10}^{20} \frac{1}{n} < \int_{9}^{20} \frac{1}{x} \ dx$.

Answer (score 1):

You can see 
$$\ln\big(\frac{21}{10}\big) \leq \sum_{n=10}^{20} \frac{1}{n}\leq \ \ln\big(\frac{20}{9}\big) \qquad \qquad (1)
$$
by exponentating both sides by we obtain 
$$
\frac{21}{10}\leq e^S \leq \frac{20}{9},\to 2.1 < 2.1577 < 2.2222
$$
where S is given by
$$
S=\sum_{n=10}^{20} \frac{1}{n}.
$$
Thus we can see the inequality is true for (1).

UPDATE because you fixed question

$$
S=\sum_{n=10}^{20} \frac{1}{n} =0.76877140$$,
thus we can see that $e^S=2.1577$, thus we can conclude (1) is true.  Note, the sum is calculated by brute force, it can be done in your head or in one line on a piece of paper.

Comment: I had my question mistyped, can you please look back to the question again. Thank You.

Comment: @user142104 I  fixed it.